# How to fashion a 5-10 Ohm resistor

Tags: resistors

I am trying to create a circuit that allows me to measure the maximum power draw of a USB socket. To do this I would like to put the 5V line under some kind of load and to generate high current, I need a circuit with between 5 and 10 Ohm resistor so that I can generate a current of 0.5 to 1A. Unfortunately, my toolbox is not very extensive - I have only 7 100 Ohm resistors and nothing rated below this. I have no very thin wire (that I can think of).

I have a USB charger doctor which will allow me to measure current draw on the USB socket. I have a multimeter which can help me measure the resistance of various things around the house. What can I use to create a resistance of 5 ohms in my circuit? This is a strange request I know but hoping someone will have a bright idea.

Comment: Easiest: buy a 5 ohm resistor from digikey.

Comment: A cup of water with salt?

Comment: Graphite is conductive, therefore you can make your own resistors, drawing them on a piece of paper (or other drawable material). But it will be hard to use, and power rating would be quite limited, maybe insufficient, but go ahead and try.

Comment: "I have only 7 100 Ohm resistors and nothing rated below this" - What other resistors do you have (or can get)? do you have other devices that can draw significant current, such such as transistors, light bulbs etc.?

Comment: Bruce Abbott I have a sample pack of 10 each of a range of resistors from 100 to 20kOhm. 3 of the 100 Ohms are already in use in other projects but I have a few of the higher rated resistors including 10x 220. Maybe I could wire all of these together in parallel? I have transistors and LEDs but no lightbulbs.

Comment: 100/7 = 14 and some ohms; 220/10 = 22 ohms. 14//22 = 8 and some ohms.

Comment: @SredniVashtar that would probably be the most logical way to do it! In the end, I used I used anrieff's suggestion of a piece of graphite. I hunted around but couldn't find a single pencil in the house but for whatever reason happen to have a stick of something called "woodless graphite". I measured this as having a resistance of 2.5 ohms so it worked perfectly to measure the max current provided by my USB sockets.